# How to avoid + sign getting replaced with a space while encoding using "parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)" in swift 2.3

Tags: swift, nsmutableurlrequest

I am using `NSMutableURLRequest`. While sending the parameters to server I have to encode it so I am encoding it using `dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) Swift 2.3` but it is removing `+` sign from the string. Is there any alternate way of doing it?

Sample Code:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: urlString)
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

urlRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

urlRequest.HTTPBody = Parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

Comment: `+` sign is not removed by `dataUsingEncoding(_:)`, but by the server side when decoding url-encoded string. To avoid this happening, you need to url-encode your `Parameters` before applying `dataUsingEncoding(_:)`.

Comment: @OOPer in other cases it is working fine but with + sing in password and mobile no country code, this issue is happening it is replacing the + sign with the space i have checked the request in charles logs as well it is Replacing the + with space

Comment: I need to repeat? You need to url-encode your `Parameters` before applying `dataUsingEncoding(_:)`.

Comment: @OOPer used stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) but still same result

Comment: @OOPer thanks for your reply it worked in other way out

Comment: Please show your solution as answer, which may help other developers. (Though, I would not recommend using Swift 2.3, as Apple is strongly suggesting we should migrate to Swift 3 **now**.)

Comment: @OOPer i agree thanks

Answer (score 1):

The plus (+) sign is a standard shortcut for a space, you have to replace the + with the %2d before encoding. Please have a look at [this Doc for other signs](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html)

```
let URL = NSURL(string: urlString)
let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!)
urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

urlRequest.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
Parameters = Parameters.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "%2b")
urlRequest.HTTPBody = Parameters.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
```

You can also url encode it if it is not helping you out  Like

```
Parameters = Parameters.stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

and then replace the (+) sign with %2d and than encode it using `dataUsingEncoding`
Hope it helps